Crystal Report Get Data
There are two columns in a table. The first column is the car brands, the second column is the model names of that brand.
When I add the XML file in the Crystal Report, I want to bring only the first model of a brand. However, it brings all the models of a brand in order. How can I make it fetch only the first model in the column?
When I add the XML file in the Crystal Report, I want to bring only the first model of a brand. However, it brings all the models of a brand in order. How can I make it fetch only the first model in the column?

Do you have DBA access to the database, or a similar equivalent that can create a Stored Procedure?  I ask because the easiest way to do this is in the SQL query that selects the data.  The query structure will differ based on the DBMS used though.  Check out this link for more information on the query structure.
